# How to disable "Pick Shortest Path" > "Fill Region" option by default?

Tags: customization, operator

Is there a way to disable this option by default when using the "Pick Shortest Path" operator? It's extremely unintuitive that this is enabled by default when it's so rarely useful.

Comment: Can you demonstrate or give an example via screenshot or gif of what you mean?

Comment: Please illustrate this with a case you have found problematic, so folks know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: How do you use _Pick Shortest Path_? With Ctrl+Shift+Left-click? That's the shortcut for _Pick Shortest Path_ wtih _Fill Region_. Simply try Ctrl+Left-click, that's the shortcut for _Pick Shortest Path_ without filling.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks, that's what I was looking for!